# Is there any way to style list type in ordered list?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am using an ordered list

```html
<ol type="A">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

which results in

[image: this image]

Is there any way I can change the styling only for the bullets (A, B and C) to make them a bit lighter and smaller, leaving the list untouched?

Comment: See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Styling_lists

Comment: The previous target was not a good duplicate as it is specifically and exclusively about changing the color. This question is about making multiple types of changes to the counter/bullet, e.g. making them smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
li {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

li span {
  font-size: 20px;
  /* example font-size, change to your liking */
}
```

```html
<ol type="A">
  <li><span>Coffee</span></li>
  <li><span>Tea</span></li>
  <li><span>Milk</span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: this will change the list style.I was looking to update only the list type.In my case only the A,B, C part

Comment: Yes. This will do the changes to A, B , and C only. Add styles to span to normalize. I hope you got the point otherwise let me know. I will create and share jsfiddle.

Comment: Setting the entire list font-size purely for the bullets - and then "opting out" for the actual items feels a little back-to-front to me. Albeit snappy! Still a good option! :-)

Comment: Code-only answers are almost never good answers.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot style the actual counter itself but you can hide and replace it with other content. That could be an image, icon or pseudo element.

Here is an example using the before pseudo element.

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: li;
}

li::before {
  content: counter(li, upper-alpha);
  color: #999; /* whatever you wish, here is a light grey... */
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px; /* whatever you need it to be... */
  margin-right: 10px;
}

li {
  counter-increment: li;
}
```

```html
<ol type="A">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

There are lots of different types of counter, I have used upper-alpha to match your posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can obviously change the colours to whatever suits your preference. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Eddie19/wa4n3htg/1/)

```css
ol { 
  counter-reset: item;
}
ol li { 
  display: block; 
}
ol li:before {
  content: counter(item) ". ";
  counter-increment: item;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```